# Best way of structuring REST URIs

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

Suppose we have the following classes and want to define REST URIs:

```
class Profile{
   IList<Upload> Uploads{get;}
}

class Upload{
  int ProfileId;
  int CategoryId;
}

class Category{
  IList<Upload> Uploads{get;}
}
```

We can define two models of URIs:

1. /profiles/{id}/uploads
2. /categories/{id}/uploads

My first question is to add a new Upload which one is preferred? and second one is, what is best practices of designing URIs?

Comment: No one is preferred, you should define both, because they differ in their behavior.

Comment: I fail to see how the shown classes and URLs are related in this question? You tend to see questions about URLs associated with Action methods. Can you clarify what it is you mean

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. In the first URI, you're adding uploads associated with a particular profile, while in the second you're adding uploads associated with a particular category. There is no "preferred" URI. They're entirely separate.

Comment: I know they are separate Uri's,  but both of them do the same work when post new Upload to both of Uri's.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify it more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the same thing in two of the endpoints then you have a design problem.

I would suggest that you first decide what main function the upload is for. Is it a profile upload or a category upload.

Make the upload for one. Then you can always assign a category for a profile according to your business needs.

You can give the categoryId as a query parameter to your profile upload endpoint like:

```
/profiles/{profileid}/uploads?categoryId={categoryid}
```